# Why can't we use "this" inside the class?

Tags: c++

E,g

```
class Test {
  public:
      void setVal(const std::string& str) {
           this.isVal = str; //This will error out
      }

  private:

      string isVal;
};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer (as opposed to a reference). So you have to say `this->isVal` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467851/why-cant-we-use-this-inside-the-class#467853), you can also do:

```
(*this).isVal = str;
```

However, it's better to do what Chris said, as it is more orthodox. This is just illustrating that you need to de-reference the pointer before calling methods on it.

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  It's perfectly legal...  (Ignoring possible operator overloads.)

Comment: I'm voting this back up. It's not the way I'd do it but it is legal, and therefore helpful. What happens if your keyboard ">" key is broken and you're on a tight deadline? :-).

Comment: ...use trigraphs? :-P :-P :-P

Comment: (Clearly a facetious comment, because there is no trigraph or digraph that makes the <> characters---but there are ones that _use_ those characters! :-P)

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it'd be that controversial. I was just trying to use the non-syntactic-sugar version to illustrate that "this" is a pointer.

Comment: anyway, this guys answer works irrespective of any operator overloads. so it's rly 100% equivalent always.

Comment: You could even do: Test &that = *this; that.isVal = str;

Comment: Well I think this kind of answer with out explanation especially for someone who is obviously a beginner isn't that great of an answer.  That could just be me though.

Comment: Whoa. Is this actually legal? Is it part of the C++ spec that (*this).isVal is functionally different from (Test b=*this; b.isVal)? Because it seems like they should both return a *new* instance similar to the original, but the former actually affects `this`.

Comment: @Chuck: Read Ates's comment more carefully. They said: "Test& that = *this; that.isVal = str;" meaning that "that" is a _reference_ to (not a new copy of) this.

Comment: Chuck, notice the & sign. it says "that" is a reference, and not an object.

Comment: I found it helpful, although the answer should probably say "But you wouldn't do this."

Answer (score 8):

You also don't really need to use `this` explicitly to access member variables/methods. You can simply say:

```
isVal = str;
```

Comment: personally, I favor explicitly using this, as it allows you to shadow parameter names (which prevents stupid dummy names) and it works with templates and dependent bases.

Answer (score 0):

For design scope you can use so :

Test::isVal = str;